# Can't register python in ExternalEvaluate

Tags: python, external-calls

I had Anaconda 3 installed on my system and python registered with the following link:

`RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python","C:\\Users\\atfai\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"]`

I recently updated some libraries in Anaconda 3 and then
`ExternalEvaluate` and `ExternalLanguage` cell stopped working giving the following error.

`StartExternalSession::noinstall: No valid installations for system Python were found with the options specified.`

So I cleared the cache of the `ExternalEvaluate` using the following command:
`` ExternalEvaluate`Private`resetCache[] ``

and attempted to register again:

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python","C:\\Users\\atfai\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"]
```

giving the following weird error:

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator::invalid: -- Message text not found -- (ExternalEvaluate`Private`reason)
```

I rebooted my computer but nothing is fixing the issue. Please help.

Comment: Make sure you follow the instructions [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html) and have `zmq` installed.

Comment: Found out the issue. After downgrading to version 3.6.7 using `conda install python = 3.6.7`, it worked again. Since I did installed new libraries and did a general update it updated my python version to 3.6.8 which is not working with `ExternalEvaluate` (mathematica 11.3). Maybe it will be supported from 12.0 onwards.

Comment: Hmm ... M11.3's ExternalEvaluate seems to work fine for me with Python 3.7.2 installed through Anaconda.

Comment: It all works for me with python 3.6.8 and 11.3.

Comment: when you do `conda update python` what version of python it is showing as the latest? Maybe because I have an older version of anaconda.

Comment: Also i made the following mistake: I registered my python distribution using `RegisterExternalEvaluator` and it showed in `FindExternalEvaluators` as registered then instead of using `UnregisterExternalEvaluator` first i directly used the `resetCache[]` command which removed it from list generated by `FindExternalEvaluators` but probably remained registered which could have bugged my installation. Can you try this and see whether you can register again and reproduce my bug?

Comment: Thanks for ```ExternalEvaluate`Private`resetCache[]```, I remove the python low version before unregistering it, and this function helps clean it out.

Answer (score 1):

It all works for me with python 3.6.8 and 11.3 as well. I tried using python 3.9.13 and python 3.7.2 and installed the pyzmq packages for each of them, but they still didn't work in mma.

Comment: This useful information can be added in as a comment as it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the evaluator

`RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python", "/usr/bin/python3"]`

[image: mathematica]

This image shows "True" in python3 as I re-calculated that after registering.